# Is it possible to send push notifications by google api that let you watch for changes to contact

Tags: php, push-notification, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-contacts-api

I am using google API for integrating calendar and syncing google contacts. Now I want to use auto-sync of google contacts. I have tried google push notification API [reference:](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push)

It's working fine for watch event's change but I am unable to use this for watching contact changes. is it possible to use the same for watching contact change resources. I tried it with url :

```
POST: https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{user-email}/full/watch
```

but no luck

Comment: Hey. I am on the same boat now, were you able to find the answer? If yes, then please share it.

Comment: No, I didn't find a way to autosync contacts just like events. But I run cron job for this work that run everyday to check if any contact is added/updated.

Answer (score 0):

The [reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push) you provided is the recommended way on how to use push notifications that inform your application when a resource changes. Currently, the Drive API supports notifications for changes to the `Files` and [`Changes`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes/watch) resources.

> To use push notifications, you need to do three things:
>
> - Register the domain of your receiving URL.
>
>   For example, if you plan to use `https://sampledomain.com/notifications` as your receiving URL, you need to register `https://sampledomain.com`.
>     Set up your receiving URL, or "Webhook" callback receiver.
> - This is an HTTPS server that handles the API notification messages that are triggered when a resource changes.
> - Set up a notification channel for each resource endpoint you want to watch.

Check the [examples](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push#making-watch-requests).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @abielita, but I already did the above steps and this works for me when there is a change in calendar event. I am asking about how to set up channel and watch uri for syncing google contacts.